# How do I get my Windows 10 PC to consistently recognize my RigExpert AA-35 ZOOM?

Tags: antenna-analyzer

I have connected my brand new RigExpert AA-35 to my Windows 10 PC via the provided USB cable, but the AA-35 does not show up in Device Manager.  There is no COM port assigned to it, nor does it show up in USB devices. Also, and this is very strange:  I can install AntScope2 (in its default directory) and read data from the AA-35 when I first run the AntScope2 after installing it.  After closing and then reopening AntScope2, however, AntScope2 does not see the AA-35.  I have to reinstall the software in order to see the AA-35 again.  I have to reinstall the software every time I want to get data from the AA-35.  Please advise.

Edit:  after email conversation with RigExpert (heard from them the very next morning!) it turns out I was looking in the wrong place for the device.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much troubleshooting, I was able to resolve the above behavior by running AntScope2 in compatibility mode for "Windows XP (Service Pack 3)"

For the record, I am running Windows 10 1909.

Comment: Does the AA-35 show up in Device Manager now?

Comment: Yes.  It always did, I was looking for it in the wrong place, expecting there to be a USB to Serial "translation" (for lack of a better term).  I edited my original text to show you where it was hiding out.

Comment: My AA-1400 shows up under "Ports (COM & LPT)" as "USB Serial Port (COM4)".  Running Win 10 1903

Comment: Alex from RigExpert "First of all, I want to note that the AA-35 Zoom analyzer is an HID device and it does not create a serial port for it when connected to a PC."